# Python2.7 + Bluez 5.61 + dbus - InterfacesRemoved never called

Tags: python, dbus, bluez

I'm trying to get a raspberry scanning for Bluetooth devices using Bluez 5.61.
I need this raspberry to be able to detect when a Bluetooth device (here, another Raspberry also using Bluez) cannot be detected anymore.
I was thinking using `InterfacesRemoved` signal from dbus but I guess I don't understand properly how it works as it's never called.
My questions:

- I'm not sure I understand properly what `interfacesAdded` and `interfacesRemoved` are used for as they are rarely called when expected (`propertiesChanged` works fine)
- Is it possible to get a signal for each advertisement message received even if the content has not changed since the last one? That would allow me to set up a timer to trigger the "non detectable anymore" event.

Here is the code I use to register my signals:

```
        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(
            self._interfaces_added,
            dbus_interface=common.OBJECT_MANAGER,
            signal_name="InterfacesAdded")

        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(
            self._interfaces_removed,
            dbus_interface=common.OBJECT_MANAGER,
            signal_name="InterfacesRemoved")

        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(
            self._properties_changed,
            dbus_interface=common.DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
            signal_name="PropertiesChanged",
            arg0=common.DEVICE_INTERFACE,
            path_keyword="path")
```

Comment: The way to test that an interface is removed is to have `bluetoothctl` open in another terminal. When you remove a device (e.g. `remove xx:xx:xx:xx;xx`) the signal should trigger. Also, is there a reason that you are still using Python 2.7 as this has been [sunset](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Thanks to that, I've noticed that even with ```bluetoothctl``` I don't get any ```remove```. I ended up trying on another Raspberry where I finally get them. Don't know why it didn't work on this one!
Thanks!
(And yeah! I'm actually using Python3! Sorry for that!)